# how to know if device in high accuracy mode

Tags: android

How can we know if the device is in high accuracy mode.

When the Google map is opened in device only mode it ask you to change to high accuracy mode. I need to implement such a thing. But i couldn't find any API that let us know the location mode.

update: i need to know this from code. i need to know if the device is currently in the device only mode, battery saver mode or high accuracy mode

Comment: check out fused location provider https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html

Comment: @bill gates check my updated answer

Comment: @goonerdroid dose that page really contains the code to get the current location mode? i was not able to find it

Comment: @maven that is not what i need. i need to get the current location mode.

Comment: check this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#LOCATION_MODE

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In 4.4 KITKAT

Go to settings>location

**Default is Device only**

[image]

Press on **MODE**

[image]

there are three options

make changes as needed

## update (through code)

**if you want to set**

```
mLocationRequest=LocationRequest.create();
mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
```

**if you want to know**:

*(following code block adapted from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/22980843/1) by [@Slava Fir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1588429/slava-fir))*

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){
    try {
        locationMode = Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(),Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE);

        } catch (SettingNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

    return (locationMode != Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF && locationMode == Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_HIGH_ACCURACY); //check location mode

}else{
    locationProviders = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
    return !TextUtils.isEmpty(locationProviders);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with Locations, you probably have to use a `LocationProvider`.

I think you can get all your answers by applying methods to the active `LocationProvider`, such as `getName()`.

Read [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationProvider.html#getName()) about available methods.