# Get Location updates in background without running Service in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, service, location, locationmanager

I want to fetch the current `Location` of the user in background. I know how it can be done using `Service` in Android. But I would like to know is there any possibilities to get user Location without running service. Like using  `BroadcastReceiver` or anything? I'm just trying to avoid running `Service` to fetch `Location`.

For Example I referred this [link](https://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/background-location-updates-on-android). But I couldn't follow how to do like this.

Any help will be appreciated. Correct me in case I'm asking anything wrong.

**EDIT:** Oh, I think in the above link he is using Service to get the Location. So I think it's not possible to get location in background without running a Service. Still suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: can we know the reason behind not using the `SERVICE` ?

Comment: @WillTorres I use lot of applications in my device. Most of them use `Service` for one or the other reason and eats my `RAM`. So from an end user perspective I feel is it worth running `Service` all time just to fetch `Location` for light weight application? So I was just looking for an alternative!

Comment: you can do scheduling like get location after every 2 hrs ... rather than keep running service in background

Comment: You mean to say scheduling using `AlarmManager`? But will that not drain the battery so much if i run a task frequently? Consider I will schedule once an hour!

Comment: best options for these kind of task are set criteria acccording to ur need

Comment: In a scheduled task I'm going to perform some heavy operation such as fetching user location and updating to server. And I'm going to repeat this once for an hour. So I would like to know the impact of that! Any help?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/25744005/5002362

Comment: How this link can help me!

Comment: click on it and read it **LOUD** :D

Answer (score -1):

You Should Implement a BroadcastReceiver that receives alarm every 2 hours. That alarm is Set by Your Activity.

When the alarm is triggered by your System, Broadcast Receiver receives it, Executes Your Process in BroadCastReceiver.

This is what i can think of.

Comment: Please read my question. I want to perform location fetching in background. By doing this in an `Activity` will not fetch in background. As soon as activity is destroyed everything will be destroyed. This can be done in `Service` instead `Activity`. But I'm not interested in `Service` and I'm asking for an alternative/