# Flutter : Check GPS Location Mode

Tags: flutter, geolocation, gps

I have project related using maps and tracking location user , for this i used [Geolocator Package](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator). I need to check current location of user , in my flow project first i check last position of user , if last position null then i check current position of user.

#### Code

```
  Position _currentPosition;
  Position get currentPosition => _currentPosition;

  Future<void> getCurrentPosition() async {
    try {
      Position lastPosition = await Geolocator().getLastKnownPosition();
      if (lastPosition != null) {
        print("Success Get Last Position...");
        _currentPosition = lastPosition;
      } else {
        final currentPosition = await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition();
        if (currentPosition != null) {
          print("Success Get Your Current Position...");
          _currentPosition = currentPosition;
        } else {
          throw "Can't Get Your Position";
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Then i calling **getCurrentPosition** Function on my button OnPressed to get location user like this :

#### Button GetLocation

```
void goToMaps() async {
    final mapsProvider = context.read<MapsProvider>();
    try {

      print('Get Location User');
      await mapsProvider.getCurrentPosition();
      print('Success Get location User');

    } catch (e) {
      globalF.showToast(message: e.toString(), isError: true, isLongDuration: true);
    }
  }
```

First Problem is , When GPS Location Mode is `Device Only` I can't get **LastPosition** or **Current Position** it never print **Success Get Location User** and still print **Get Location User**.

Second Problem is , When Gps Location Mode is `Battery Saving` user location i got is very inaccurate, compared i used mode `High Accuracy`.

My question is , How can i check if gps location mode != **High Accuracy** , then i can show warning user to set the gps to High Accuracy.

Similiar Like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25743743/how-to-know-if-device-in-high-accuracy-mode)

Thank's.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the second problem, it happens because in *High Accuracy* mode android uses both GPS and network location, but in *Battery Saving* mode GPS module is turned off. If it was native Android, you could check [provider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location#getProvider()) of the location if you get location from LocationManager. But provider is not available in Flutter in [Position](https://pub.dev/documentation/geolocator/latest/geolocator/Position-class.html) class. You can instead use [accuracy](https://pub.dev/documentation/geolocator/latest/geolocator/Position/accuracy.html). If it is greater than a threshold and not suitable for your application, you can suggest the user to turn on High Accuracy mode.

Another options would be to use other package than *Geolocator* (however I'm not aware of any package that provides necessary interface) or to modify source code of *Geolocatior* so that it provides information about which mode is currently active.